# Counting integers in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, integer

I have to create a for loop in matlab that will fill x with counting integers from 1 to 3 and display only the final result. Currently x: 0 0 0. I'm new to matlab so I'm not sure how the syntax should be (also tried to google it and I'm still confused) thank you for all the help!

Comment: If you don't know where to start, Stack Overflow is not the right place to be. Why don't you read some of the introductory tutorials that the company behind MATLAB puts out? It's a way better way to learn than to ask here, or to try random sequences of letters... https://www.mathworks.com/support/learn-with-matlab-tutorials.html

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1:3
```

In Matlab you should try to avoid for loops as they are slow compared to the matrix operations